# Does $b \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $a \equiv b \pmod p$ imply $(a,p) =1$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $p$ be a prime. If I understood everything correctly [here on page 3](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/solovaystrassen.pdf) is the claim that $$b \not \equiv 1 \pmod p \text{ and } a \equiv b \pmod p$$ imply that $(a,p) =1$.

I do not understand why this should be true. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Doesn't look right to me.  Where did you come across it?

Comment: @Mike: See my edit.

Comment: Not positive, but I think you found a typo.  Not very familiar with it, but after looking up the Jacobi symbol, it appears $\left(\frac{b}{p}\right)$ implies $b\not\equiv0\pmod p$.

Comment: Actually, I'm half wrong.  b can't be equivalent to 1 either since there's clearly an integer $x$ such that $x^2\equiv1\pmod p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a \equiv b \pmod p$ implies $(a,p) = (b,p)$.
So if you need to conclude that $(a,p)=1$ (or equivalently $(b,p)=1$) you need the hypothesis $b \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ (instead of $b \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$).

Answer (score 2):

For $(a,b,p)=(2,4,2)$ is false.

$4 \not\equiv 1  (\mod 2)$ and $2 \equiv 4 (\mod 2)$, but $(2,2)=2$.